# voltage reading 4v at outlet

Tags: electrical

i am attempting to create a 120v outlet to plug in LED light strip in ceiling.  The existing lights in the ceiling area-wire are two separate 24v lines going to two strings that have multiple 5 watt lights that are stuck into the light wire by means of two prongs, much like 12v landscape lights.
I connected the hot and neutral wires (pig-tailed them to the outlet due to large gauge wiring from two-wire light wire.  I used my multimeter set on AC and read only 4v; then tried reading on DC setting and read zero.  I did the same on the other powered wire and it read the same for AC and DC settings.  I realize it is possible that there may be a 24v transformer somewhere in the ceiling from the switch, but it should have read something on the DC setting.  I'm wondering if I should connect both power wires together in the outlet box.  Any answers would be appreciated.

Comment: Hello,  and welcome to Home Improvement. It's hard to understand what you mean;  would you post a diagram, or a picture of the wiring?

Comment: I confirmed that there is a transformer in the ceiling due to the 4v reading.  I should have realized it, thanks anyway.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Would you mind posting an answer to your question, so that future visitors can benefit? Thanks.